# How can I include a .eps figure within a Tikz simple flow chart?

Tags: r, latex, flowchart, eps, tikz

I would like to create a simple flow chart in latex with the TikZ package similar to the following example

http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/simple-flow-chart/

However I would like to include figures (a time series plot created in R, as eps or something else) within the flowchart (e.g. for example within a {block}?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=4.5em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
    minimum height=2em]

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
    % Place nodes
    \node [block] (init) {initialize model};
    \node [cloud, left of=init] (expert) {expert};
    \node [cloud, right of=init] (system) {system};
    \node [block, below of=init] (identify) {identify candidate models};
    \node [block, below of=identify] (evaluate) {evaluate candidate models};
    \node [block, left of=evaluate, node distance=3cm] (update) {update model};
    \node [decision, below of=evaluate] (decide) {is best candidate better?};
    \node [block, below of=decide, node distance=3cm] (stop) {stop};
    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (init) -- (identify);
    \path [line] (identify) -- (evaluate);
    \path [line] (evaluate) -- (decide);
    \path [line] (decide) -| node [near start] {yes} (update);
    \path [line] (update) |- (identify);
    \path [line] (decide) -- node {no}(stop);
    \path [line,dashed] (expert) -- (init);
    \path [line,dashed] (system) -- (init);
    \path [line,dashed] (system) |- (evaluate);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Thanks,
Jan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [another example](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/connecting-text-and-graphics/) shows, it is possible to use `\includegraphics` in a `tikzpicture` environment. Have you tried this?

And of course there is the obligatory mentioning of `pgfplots`. Time series or other data visualization can be performed using this package instead of including graphics :).

Comment: excellent example. thanks. I am exploring the magics of tikzpicture and pgfplots at the moment. Very nice.